# VLOOKUP using batch scripting

Tags: windows, scripting, vbscript

I am new to scripting and perform lot of activity as an analyst using excel sheets. 
I have two files with list of items in it. 
File1 contains 1 column
File2 contains 2 columns.

I want to check if the list present in column1 of file2 is same as in column1 of file2. If yes then it should print column1File1, column1File2 and coulmn2File2 in file3 else it should print "NA", column1File2, column2File2 in file3.

Please help, It will simplify my work a lot.

Comment: *I want to check if the list present in column1 of file2 is same as in column1 of file2.* Yes, they will be. :)

Answer (score 0):

I made this program a while ago, although it will iterate through sheets in 1 workbook, and compare cell by cell, it may set you in the right direction. It would take a cell in 1 "master" sheet and then iterate through each sheet to find that in a particular column. After it found it the counter would increment, then it would take the next cell in the master sheet and so on. you could alter to use multiple books and take whatever cells you want and compare them.

```
Sub Open_Excel()


'Use worksheetNum as sheet to read/write data
Set currentWorkSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheetNum)

'How many rows are used in the current worksheet
usedRowsCount = currentWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'Use current worksheet cells for values
Set Cells = currentWorksheet.Cells

    'Loop through each row in the worksheet  
    For curRow = startRow to (usedRowsCount)            

        'Get computer name to ping to
        strEmailAddressSource = Cells(curRow,colEmailAddressSource).Value
        strServerSource = Cells(curRow,colHostserverSource).Value
        strLocationSource = Cells(curRow,colLocationSource).Value

        'make the values unique
        strconcatenation = strServerSource & strLocationSource

        Call Comparison()

    Next

End Sub

'********************************************************************************************
'**** Comparison
'********************************************************************************************
'Comparison test

Sub Comparison()

'choose the worksheets to go through
For  worksheetCounter = 6 to 9 'workSheetCount

Set currentWorkSheetComparison = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheetCounter)

    usedRowsCountNew = currentWorkSheetComparison.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'First row to start the comparison from
    For rowCompare = 2 to (usedRowsCountNew)

    strEmailLot = currentWorkSheetComparison.Cells(rowCompare,colEmailAddressLot).Value

    comp1 = StrComp(strEmailAddressSource,strEmailLot,0)

    comp2 = StrComp(strconcatenation,reportConcat,0)



     'check if the values match
        If ((comp1 = 0) AND (comp2 = 0)) THEN
        countvalue = countvalue + 1 
        End If

    Next
Next

End Sub
```